# What is the Efficient way to right rotate list circularly in python without inbuilt function

Tags: python-3.x, runtime-error

```
def circularArrayRotation(a, k, queries):
    temp=a+a
    indexToCountFrom=len(a)-k

    for val in queries:
       print(temp[indexToCountFrom+val])
```

I am having this code to perform the rotation .

This function takes list as a, the number of time it needs to be rotated as k, and last is query which is a list containing indices whose value is needed after the all rotation.

My code works for all the cases except some bigger ones.

Where i am doing it wrong ?

link: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/circular-array-rotation/problem

Comment: "some bigger ones": you probably run into a timeout. You should find a solution that does not need to create a new list (`temp`). Make the index wrap around to 0 when it exceeds the end.

Comment: nopes ! i am getting index out of range error on bigger cases.

Comment: then you are doing it wrong. It really is the solution. You must wrap around (use modulo operator) to stay within range.

Comment: Please make yourserf literate with the concept of ring buffer. Then you will know the reason to use the modular division in this solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably run into a timeout when you concatenate large lists with `temp = a + a`.

Instead, don't create a new list, but use the modulo operator in your loop:

```
   print(a[(indexToCountFrom+val) % len(a)])
```

Comment: surprisingly it worked .Can u please explain the purpose of attaching the "%len(a)" here ? I am not getting it.

Comment: It makes sure that you never get an index equal or greater than len(a). Check the documentation on the modulo operator.